# Azure Function App (Python) on App Service Plan Container Timeout with Failed to get HTTP Response After Warmup

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I am having an Az Function App running for my python code. Sometimes I encounter the following errors and the function app & app service keeps on restarting:
[image]

I have already tried add WEBSITES_PORT, PORT, WEBSITE_PORT & WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT(to max 1800), but none worked.

PS: The Azure Function App is backed by App Service Plan (Isolated Tier)

Comment: Based on docker?

Comment: No. Its a python function app, deploying the python project directly, not using docker image.

Comment: Do you have Always On enabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan#always-on

Comment: Yes. It is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you have tried so many ways, then I believe you must be experienced, so at this time, when the methods currently available on Google are invalid, we analyze the logs of the azure web app at this time, I think it is the most effective Way out.

[image]